# Debugger is not working when call a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, client-side

I have placed a debugger inside a function and the function call when click on the save button. debugger is called and paused but I can't able to see the code also I can press the F10 and move line by line but I can't see the code.

Note: That html contents are placed inside the iframe.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried typing Command-O and searching for your script?

Comment: @HunanRostomyan you mean open the script using ctrl+o? I tried.

Comment: Is the script embedded in the html directly or you'r sourcing it?

Comment: HTML directly and that code was placed inside the IFrame.

Comment: @MerbinJoe, you can create a new javascript file and write your all client side codes inside this file. Then refer your js file from your aspx file. It will enable you to view all scripts inside your js file.

Comment: @AbhilashPA ok, I will try. But may I know why it is not working? is this chrome development bug? after updating chrome only this problem.

Comment: @MerbinJoe, Sorry, I also unaware of the reason. I also got the same problem and I have managed it to add scripts inside a js file.